# How to Create a Sparse Tree Based on Two or More Properties

Tags: org-mode, sparse-tree, org-properties

I have multiple headlines with two Properties A and B, storing the numerical values 0, 1, 2, 3, e.g.:

```
* Headline
:PROPERTIES:
:A: 2
:B: 3
:END:
```

I want to create a sparse tree based on the values stored in A ***and*** B.

For example, I want to be able to create a sparse tree containing all headlines where A=2 and B=3.

I know that you can filter for a single property and its value with C-c / p.

But is there a way to do that for two or more properties and their respective values at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! org-mode has a slightly mixed language, around the words "tag" and "match", but you can use `C-c / m`. See the documentation for exactly how it works - https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html (you want to pay attention around `+work-boss+PRIORITY="A"+Coffee="unlimited"+Effort<2+With={Sarah\|Denny}+SCHEDULED>="<2008-10-11>"`)

but in your case for instance, `A=2&B=3` would work, so it could be `(org-match-sparse-tree nil "A=2&B=3")` or `C-c / m A=2&B=3 RET`.

Comment: Thank you @Trevoke! The first expression (A=2&B=3) works exactly as I want it to. However, there seems to be an issue with the second one ("A=\"2\"&B=\"3\"): when I use it, all headlines in the sparse tree become visible.

Furthermore, the second expression seems a bit complicated and also involves quite a bit of typing.Is it possible to make life easier here, for instance, by predefining certain expressions or storing them within a function?

Comment: Let's assume I'm wrong about the second one for now then, I'll edit my answer and remove that. As for your question, you should make a separate question out of that, because there may be multiple answers, e.g. creating a custom agenda view :)